# How to determine $\mathrm{rank}(p(A))$ if you know the rational canonical form of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

For example, let $A$ be a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that
$$
\text{RCF of } A = C \left[ x + 1 \right] \oplus C \left[ (x + 1) ^ 2 \right] \oplus C \left[ (x^2 + x + 1) ^ 3 \right] \oplus C \left[ (x^3 + x + 1) ^ 2 \right]
$$
[where $C \left[ f(x) \right] = \text{the companion matrix of } f(x)$]

How can I get the rank of the matrix $A ^ 3 + I$?

---

Since applying an polynomial to the $\text{RCF of } A$ is the same as applying a polynomial to every component on the $\text{RCF of } A$, it is enough to work on every component in order to determine the rank of $p(A)$ [in our case, $p (x) = x^3 + 1$].

Since we are in $\mathbb{F}_2 [x]$, then $x ^ 3  + 1 = (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1)$.

I tried to find the $\text{RCF of } g \left( C \left[ f(x) \right] \right)$ (where $f,g$ are polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2 [x]$)
by considering some cases, but I didn't managed to do it.
I suspect that in the case of $\gcd (f, g) = 1$, the $\text{RCF of } g \left( C \left[ f(x) \right] \right)$ is $C \left[ f(x) \right]$, but didn't managed to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to handle the easiest case: note that if $f\mid g$, then $g(C[f]) = 0$.

Generally speaking, we will have $\dim \ker(g(C[f])) = \deg(\gcd(f,g))$, and then the rank can be obtained via the rank-nullity theorem. With this fact, it is easy to see that for each of the summands in the RCF, the ranks will be $0,1,4,6$. Adding these together gives us our answer: the rank of $A^3 + I$ is $11$.

---

Regarding your conjecture: your conjecture is incorrect, but the case where $f,g$ are relatively prime is important. For such $f,g$, the matrix $g(C[f])$ is invertible.

To see that this is the case, note that by Bezout's lemma, there exist polynomials $p,q$ such that
$$
p(x)f(x) + q(x) g(x) = 1.
$$
Plugging $C[f]$ into this equation yields
$$
p(C[f])f(C[f]) + q(C[f])g(C[f]) = I \implies q(C[f])g(C[f]) = I,
$$
so that $g(C[f])$ has inverse $q(C[f])$.

---

Regarding the fact that $\dim \ker(g(C[f]) = \deg(\gcd(f,g))$:

There are only two ways that I can think of proving this: one is to appeal to the existence of an algebraic closure, so that we can use Jordan canonical form. The other, which I present here, uses some abstract algebra that you might not be comfortable with.

So, here is the abstract algebra based proof. Suppose that $f$ has degree $n$. Note that $C[f]$ is the matrix of the linear operator
$$
\mu_x: \Bbb F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \to \Bbb F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle, \quad \mu_x(g(x)) = xg(x).
$$
Note that as a vector space over $\Bbb F$, $V:=\Bbb F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$ has dimension $n$ because it is spanned by the independent elements $1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}$.

On the other had, $g(\mu_x) = \mu_{g(x)}$. The image of $\mu_{g(x)}$ is $\langle g(x) \rangle$ (the ideal generated by $g(x)$), which is equal to $\langle d(x) \rangle$ where $d = \gcd(f,g)$. Let $m = \deg(d)$; note that $m \leq n$. An element of $\langle d \rangle \subset V$ can be expressed in the form $d(x)p(x)$, where $\deg(d(x)p(x)) \leq n-1$. It follows that the set $\{d(x),xd(x),\dots,x^{n-m-1}d(x)\}$ is a basis of $\langle d(x)\rangle$.

Thus, we conclude that the image of $g(\mu_x)$ has dimension $n-m$. Thus, the rank of $g(C[f])$ is $n-m$, or equivalently the dimension of the kernel of $g(C[f])$ is $m$, which was what we wanted.

---

Here's an attempt to translate the above proof into a more linear algebraic context, essentially in the style of Hoffman and Kunze.

To begin, apply Bezout's lemma again to note that there exists polynomials $p,q$ such that
$$
p(x)f(x) + q(x)g(x) = d(x).
$$
Plugging in $C := C[f]$ yields
$$
p(C)f(C) + q(C)g(C) = d(C) \implies
q(C)g(C) = d(C),
$$
which means that $\operatorname{rank}(d(C)) \leq \operatorname{rank}(g(C))$. On the other hand, because $d|g$, we can let $g_0 = g/d$ and find that
$$
g(C) = g_0(C)d(C),
$$
which means that $\operatorname{rank}(d(C)) \geq \operatorname{rank}(g(C))$. Thus, $\operatorname{rank}(d(C)) = \operatorname{rank}(g(C))$. With that, it suffices to determine the rank or nullity of $d(C)$, where $d \mid f$.

Note that $\Bbb F^n$ is a $C$-cyclic subspace, and that $v = (1,0,\dots,0)$ is a [cyclic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace) for $C$. It follows that the image of $d(C)$ is the $d(C)$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$. From there, we can see that the annihilating polynomial of $d(C)v$ must be $p = f/d$. Thus, the $d(C)$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$ has dimension equal to $\deg(p) = \deg(f) - \deg(d)$. So, we conclude that the rank of $d(C)$ is equal to $\deg(f) - \deg(d)$, which was what we wanted.

---

**Thoughts on the RCF of $g(C[f])$:**

One easy case occurs when $f(x) = (x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x - \lambda_k)$ (so that $f$ is diagonalizable) and $g(\lambda_i) \neq g(\lambda_j)$ for all $i \neq j$. In that case, $g(C[f])$ has RCF $C[(x - f(\lambda_1) \cdots (x - f(\lambda_k))]$.

Another easy case occurs when $f(x) = (x - \lambda)^k$ and $g$ is not divisible by $(x-\lambda)$. In that case, it turns out that $g(C[f])$ has RCF $C[(x - f(\lambda))^k]$.

It is also helpful to note that whenever $f_1,f_2$ are relatively prime, we have
$$
C[f_1(x)f_2(x)] \cong C[f_1(x)] \oplus C[f_2(x)].
$$

It's not clear how these observations might be joined into a general rule.

**An example computation of the RCF of $g(C[f])$:**

Take $f(x) = (x^2 + 1)^2$ with coefficients in $\Bbb R$, and consider the polynomial $g(x) = x^3 + x$. We note that the Jordan form of $C[f]$ is given by
$$
J = \pmatrix{i&1\\&i\\&&-i&1\\&&&-i}.
$$
Correspondingly, the derivative of $g$ is $g'(x) = 3x^2 + 1$, so we compute
$$
g(J) = \pmatrix{g(i) & g'(i)\\&g(i)\\&&g(-i)&g'(-i)\\&&&g(-i)}
= \pmatrix{0 & -2\\&0\\ &&0&-2\\&&&0}.
$$
The Jordan form of this matrix is
$$
J_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\&0\\&&0&1\\&&&0},
$$
and depending on your definition of the companion matrix, either $J_2$ or its transpose is already in RCF. We find that the RCF of $g(C[f])$ is given by
$$
C[x^2] \oplus C[x^2].
$$
On the other hand, suppose that $g(x) = x^3 - x$. This time we find that
$$
g(J) = \pmatrix{-2i & -4\\&-2i\\&&2i&-4\\&&&2i}.
$$
The corresponding Jordan matrix is
$$
J_2 = \pmatrix{-2i & 1\\&-2i\\&&2i&1\\&&&2i},
$$
and the JCF of $J_2$ is given by
$$
C[(x^2 + 4)^2].
$$

Comment: Is it possible to determine the RCF of p(A)?

Comment: @ufer324 I don't know of any easy way to do so. As a computational method, it's possible to go from the RCF to the Jordan form over the algebraic closure, obtain the Jordan form of $p(A)$, and go from there to the RCF. However, I don't know of any nice direct relationship between the RCF of $A$ and $p(A)$ directly.

Comment: @ufer324 See my edit; I've added some thoughts on the RCF of $p(A)$.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me! :)